# Using AJAX to Update WordPress Theme

Tags: themes, updates

I am trying to create a wizard installer for my custom WordPress theme and I have succeeded to some extent.
The license has been checked and the template is ready to be updated, and this is done correctly on the update page(update.php?action=upgrade-theme)
but how can the update process be done in the background using Ajax?

Thank you

Comment: Why AJAX? The built-in wp_update_themes() runs as a scheduled background task. You'll need server-side code to update the files. Yes you could trigger it or similar code from a wp_ajax handler or a REST endpoint handler but I'm not sure what this gets you.

Comment: Thank you
wp_update_theme() was a good suggestion and worked properly